# unable to compile default_robot_hw_sim.cpp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to compile default_robot_hw_sim.cpp on Indigo under Ubuntu 14. I do not see any issue tracking this so I  believe there is an issue with my environment. Can someone give me an idea where to look for resolution. I was able to compile in Hydro under Ubuntu 13.

```
default_robot_hw_sim.dir/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp.o
Built target gazebo_ros_control
/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool gazebo_ros_control::DefaultRobotHWSim::initSim(const string&, ros::NodeHandle, gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, const urdf::Model*, std::vector<transmission_interface::TransmissionInfo>)’:
/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:155:78: error: ‘struct transmission_interface::ActuatorInfo’ has no member named ‘hardware_interface_’
       const std::string& hardware_interface = transmissions[j].actuators_[0].hardware_interface_;
                                                                              ^
make[2]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174505/unable-to-compile-default_robot_hw_sim.cpp/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrico Villagrossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19434/enrico-villagrossi/) on 2014-07-04**:
The problem seems to be in trasmission_info.h where the member hardware_interfaces_ in the struct ActuatorInfo has been changed from (in Hydro):
std::string> hardware_interface_;
to (in Indigo):
std::vectorstd::string hardware_interfaces_;

but the change was not receipt in default_robot_hw_sim.cpp

Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the looks of it, you are using hydro's `ros_control`, but are building `gazebo_ros_control` from source using the `indigo-devel` branch.

If you are working in hydro, but need ros_control features that are only released into indigo, you should be able to build the `indigo-devel` versions of `ros_control` and `gazebo_ros_control` in an otherwise Hydro environment. Otherwise just stick to hydro-only code.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrico Villagrossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19434/enrico-villagrossi/) on 2014-07-04**:
You are right. My ROS packages were aligned with Indigo while my gazebo_ros_control was at the Hydro version. The problem was with the git clone where I didn't specified the right branch of the libraries for indigo-devel... Thank you! Enrico

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-04**:
So r u saying that clone does not work how do I get the right packages Indigo-devel. I am working only in Indigo I have no hydro that I know of. All downloading was done via ubuntu software center. Please tell me the in detail how to resolve. I was using git clone to get the source for gazebo_ros_pkgs.

**Comment by [Enrico Villagrossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19434/enrico-villagrossi/) on 2014-07-05**:
For the package gazebo_ros_pkgs you have to specify the right branch to the git clone for indigo-devel: git clone -b indigo-devel https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git othewise you will clone the hydro-devel...

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-06**:
Thanks....I am able to compile now.  I had to compile it several times for some reason could not get it to compile in none shot.